# Cloud Armor | allow multiple request paths in one line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I would like to allow only some of the request paths within one line rule like this

```
'[service,register,state]'.contains(request.path) && '[AT,DE,CH]'.contains(origin.region_code)
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to tackle this since this since the last path with `origin.region_code` works fine for multiple occurences but not the `request.path`

The old way with only one string works `request.path.contains('service')`
But I need to make a map or working list out of it like `'[service,register,state]'.contains(request.path)`

The google docu does not help much [here](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#allow_or_deny_traffic_for_a_request_uri_that_matches_a_regular_expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay it seems that the anwser was rather easy and regex a`like

just use this

```
request.path.matches('service|register|state')
```

Comment: Tested and working, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The below example also works!

```
request.path.matches('service/test/example/|register/sample/example/|state/abc/example')
```